# IntegrityError: insert or update on table "carts_cart_items" violates foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

```
DETAIL: Key (cartitem_id)=(11) is not present in table "carts_cartitem"."carts_cart_items_cartitem_id_197166f7_fk_carts_cartitem_id"
DETAIL:  Key (cartitem_id)=(11) is not present in table "carts_cartitem".
```

guys what I missing in this error:

Full Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 21, in
>    main() File "manage.py", line 17, in main
>   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 381, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute() File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 375, in execute
>   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 323, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **cmd_options) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 364, in execute output = self.handle(*args, **options) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 83, in wrapped res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
>   line 234, in handle fake_initial=fake_initial, File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 117, in migrate state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan,
>   full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards state = self.apply_migration(state,
>   migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 245, in apply_migration state = migration.apply(state,
>   schema_editor) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py",
>   line 124, in apply operation.database_forwards(self.app_label,
>   schema_editor, old_state, project_state) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py",
>   line 249, in database_forwards schema_editor.alter_field(from_model,
>   from_field, to_field) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
>   line 520, in alter_field return self._alter_many_to_many(model,
>   old_field, new_field, strict) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
>   line 867, in _alter_many_to_many
>   new_field.remote_field.through._meta.get_field(new_field.m2m_reverse_field_name()),
>   File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
>   line 535, in alter_field old_db_params, new_db_params, strict) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\schema.py",
>   line 122, in _alter_field new_db_params, strict, File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
>   line 758, in _alter_field self.execute(self._create_fk_sql(model,
>   new_field, "*fk*%(to_table)s_%(to_column)s")) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
>   line 137, in execute cursor.execute(sql, params) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 99, in execute return super().execute(sql, params) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 67, in execute return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params,
>   many=False, executor=self._execute) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers return executor(sql, params, many,
>   context) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89,
>   in **exit** raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from
>   exc_value File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 84, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>   django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table
>   "carts_cart_items" violates foreign key constraint
>   "carts_cart_items_cartitem_id_197166f7_fk_carts_cartitem_id" DETAIL:
>   Key (cartitem_id)=(11) is not present in table "carts_cartitem".

models:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return item.title

class Cart(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem, null=True, blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Item, null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = "updated"


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Card Id: %s" %(self.i
```

Comment: What are you trying to do when you got this error? Add traceback of error

Comment: In your case, do you want to link one cartitem to more than one cart. If no, then the relation b/w them should be one-to-many not many-to-many.

Comment: @weAreStarDust I have added the traceback, thanks